# How to pull processing % from opening workbook for a status bar update?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a few large macros that open/close large workbooks, and unfortunately these workbooks take a little time to open/load/calculate. When I open them manually, I can see the opening percentage on the initial screen:

[image]

And the calculation % on the status bar of the file here:

[image: Processing picture]

What I'm wondering is how I can grab these percentages and relay it to my main workbook's status bar to something of the effect of:

```
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Opening production file... " & Workbooks("Book1").LoadingPercentage & " of the way complete..."
```

I'm a big fan of updating my users through status bars, so when the status bar just says `Opening production file...` and hangs for 20 seconds, they might grow concerned that the program froze. I *could* just have a counter that increments every second, but that would be inconsistent and wouldn't necessarily prove that the program hasn't froze/crashed.

Is there a way that I can grab this number from an opening workbook? Or is there any kind of clever workaround? I skimmed through the properties of `Workbooks("Book1").` and didn't see anything I could use.

Comment: You can't do that unless you're the one unwrapping the XML and processing the file - i.e. do Excel's job and you can have a % progress.

Comment: Not sure you can access Excel object model to get the progress until workbook is opened. Take a look at AutoIt for screenscraping.

Comment: @Mat'sMug What if I say, took the average time that it takes to open the file in seconds each time, stored that value somewhere, then did something like `currenttime/averageopentime & "% of the way there...`. Too much work?

Comment: @omegastripes Not too familiar with screenscraping - I'll look into it - thanks.

Comment: @omegastripes that misses the point - OP *already has* Excel open and VBA code running. Trying to get a %progress to show up in progress bar when programmatically opening a large file. Right, dwirony?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes Mat that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

This instruction runs synchronously:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
```

The instruction after that will only run *after* the file has finished loading and the `wb` object reference is set.

And as far as I know there's no way to open a workbook asynchronously in Excel. If there was, then the API could have exposed events such as `OnOpenProgress` or similar, which you could have handled, say, like this:

```
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

'...

Private Sub app_OnOpenProgress(ByVal path As String, ByVal percentComplete As Double, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.StatusBar = "Opening " & path & "... (" & Format(percentComplete, "0.0%") & ")"
End Sub
```

But that's not something that's currently possible AFAIK.

The only way I can see this done, is by implementing your own `Workbooks.Open` method that returns a `Excel.Workbook` object. Needless to say the cost/benefits ratio is astronomical (and not in favor of the benefits).

The best solution is to suck it up and do everything possible to minimize workbook file size, mostly by storing data in a database, not in Excel workbooks.

Comment: Ah that's such a pity, but it makes sense... Guess I'll just have to tell my users to be extra patient!

Comment: @dwirony you could always ask for the feature on Microsoft Connect :-)